# How are expired vnodes reflected in vnode_disk_storage statistics?

Tags: cnosdb

```
usage_schema ❯ select * from vnode_disk_storage order by time desc limit 20;
+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+
| time                          | database     | node_id             | tenant | vnode_id | value     |
+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+
| 2024-01-22T23:58:24.436714306 | usage_schema | 1703756289290769956 | cnosdb | 3        | 105401570 |
| 2024-01-22T23:58:14.437178209 | usage_schema | 1703756289290769956 | cnosdb | 3        | 105401570 |
| 2024-01-22T23:58:04.436457352 | usage_schema | 1703756289290769956 | cnosdb | 3        | 105401570 |
```

Through the vnode_disk_storage table in usage_scehma, you can see the storage size of the current vnode. I want to know, if a vnode expires, how will its usage be reflected in this table? According to my experience using http_data_in, the value in the table is a monotonically increasing value. So how does the reduced usage of expiration deletion be reflected in the vnode table?